# What is too complicated about $y=x^{xy}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

While playing with Desmos today, I typed the equation $y=x^{xy}$ and the graph came out to be [image]

I clicked the *Learn More* option given near my equation and Desmos said: Sometimes the calculator detects that an equation is too complicated to plot perfectly in a reasonable amount of time. When this happens, the equation is plotted at lower resolution.

What is the complication?

Comment: Well, for every value of $x$ it needs to solve a non-trivial equation to find out $y$ so the issue could come from there.

Comment: Think yourself and find the value of $y$ for $x=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: Could you rescale the plot for $0\leq x\leq 1.5$; it would be much better. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I edited it.

Comment: Thanks for doing it.

Comment: I don't see that message here, and I don't see it when I enter the same formula in Desmos myself. I do see that message for $y=x^{xy^x}.$ Are you sure this is the graph you were looking at when you saw that message?

Comment: @DavidK I apologise. After ClaudeLeibovici's comment I EDITED this post and the message disappeared in the newer plot.

Comment: That explains the difference. If I zoom out then the message appears. I assume whatever Desmos is doing to plot this graph, it is computing fewer points than usual. Maybe it doesn't recognize how to solve the equation using the Lambert function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple in terms of Lambert function
$$y=x^{xy}\implies y=-\frac{W(-x \log (x))}{x \log (x)}$$ In order to stay in the real domain, you need that
$$x \log(x) \geq \frac 1e \implies x \lt \frac{1}{e W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)}=1.32110\cdots$$

We also have
$$y'=\frac{ e^{-2 W(-x \log (x))}}{W(-x \log (x))+1}(\log (x)+1)$$ which cancels at $x=\frac 1e$ and at this point $y=e W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)=0.756945\cdots$

I think that we have a good description of your function.

Comment: I think Desmos thought it is too complicated because of the Lambert function.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{align}&y=(x^x)^y\\
\implies &y^{\frac 1y}=x^x\\ \implies &y^{-1}\ln y=x\ln x\\
\implies &-y^{-1}\ln y^{-1}=x\ln x\\
\implies &y^{-1}\ln y^{-1}=-x\ln x\\ 
\implies &\ln y^{-1} e^{\ln {y^{-1}}}=-x\ln x\\
\implies &W\left(\ln y^{-1} e^{\ln {y^{-1}}}\right)=W\left(-x\ln x\right)\\
\implies &\ln y^{-1}=W\left(-x\ln x \right)\\
\implies &y^{-1}=e^{W\left(-x\ln x\right)}\\
\implies &y=e^{-W\left(-x\ln x\right)}\end{align}$$

This implies, your function is a non-elementary function and can be written as

$$f(x)=e^{-W\left(-x\ln x\right)}.$$

---

Then, note that $W(x)$ is real for only $x≥-\frac 1e$.

This means , we have

$$\begin{align}-x&\ln x≥-\frac 1e,\thinspace x>0\\
\implies &x\ln x≤\frac 1e \\
\implies &\ln x e^{\ln x}≤\frac 1e\\
\implies &W\left(\ln xe^{\ln x}\right)≤W\left(\frac 1e\right)\\
\implies &\ln x≤W\left(\frac 1e\right)\\
\implies &0<x≤e^{W\left(1/e\right)}≈1.3211\end{align}$$.